# Sending custom parameter on authentication

Tags: servicestack

I'm a servicestack newbie. I'm trying to figure out how to send custom parameter on authentication.
As far as I understood, that's the step to authenticate a client and than execute a set of call within a session

```
var jsonClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:55679/");
var authResponse = client.Send(new Authenticate
{
    provider = "myProvider",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "pwd",
    RememberMe = true,
}); 
var jResponse = jsonClient.Get<CountriesResponse>(request);
Console.WriteLine(jResponse.Countries.Count);
```

So far so good, I configurated my apphost as following and everything works as expected.

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
     new MyAuthProvider(), 
}));
```

What should I do if, instead of sending ServiceStack.Authenticate, I'd like to send my MyAuthenticate
request that has same custom properties, somenthing like this?

```
var authResponse = client.Send(new MyAuthenticate
{
    provider = "myProvider",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "pwd",
    RememberMe = true,
    AppId = "AppId",
    ProjectId = "ProjectId"
});
```

My goal is to send custom parameter while I'm authenticating the user, not just those allowed by Authenticate built-in request, and than store those extra parameter within my CustomUserSession.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Sending additional info on QueryString or HttpHeaders

As you can't change the built-in `Authenticate` Request DTO, one way to send additional metadata is to add extra info on the `QueryString` or HTTP `Headers`.

If you wanted to use the .NET Service Clients to do this you would need to use the RequestFilter, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl) {
    RequestFilter = req => { 
        req.QueryString["AppId"] = appId;
        req.QueryString["ProjectId"] = appId;
    }
};

var authResponse = client.Send(new Authenticate { ... });
```

Otherwise creating custom Request is often more flexible using ServiceStack's built-in [HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils), e.g:

```
var url = "{0}/auth/myProvider".Fmt(BaseUrl)
    .AddQueryParam("AppId", appId)
    .AddQueryParam("ProjectId", projectId);

var authResponse = url.PostJsonToUrl(new Authenticate { ... });
```

On the server the additional data will be available in the `QueryString` of the current request which you can get from `IServiceBase` or `IRequest` args, e.g:

```
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    ...
    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, 
        IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        ...
        var customSession = (CustomUserSession)session;
        customSession.AppId = authService.Request.QueryString["AppId"];
        customSession.ProjectId = authService.Request.QueryString["ProjectId"];
        return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
    }
}
```

### Custom `Meta` dictionary now available on Authenticate Request DTO

To make this use-case a little easier a new `Dictionary<string,string> Meta` property was added on the `Authenticate` DTO which makes calling from the Typed Service Clients a little nicer since you don't have to use a filter, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl);

var authResponse = client.Send(new Authenticate {
     ... 
     Meta = new Dictionary<string, string> { {"AppId", appId}, {"ProjectId", pId} },
});
```

Which you can access from the Authenticate DTO directly, e.g:

```
var authRequest = (Authenticate)authService.Request.Dto;
customSession.AppId = authRequest.Meta["AppId"];
customSession.ProjectId = authRequest.Meta["ProjectId"];
```

The new `Meta` property is available from **v4.0.35+** that's currently [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

### Use your own Custom Authentication Service

A more disruptive alternative approach to be able to use your own `MyAuthenticate` DTO is to handle the authentication request in your own Service and then delegate to the AuthService, e.g:

```
public class MyAuthenticate : Authenticate 
{ 
    public string AppId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
}

public class MyAuthServices : Service
{
    public object Any(MyAuthenticate request)
    {
        using (var auth = base.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>())
        {
            var response = auth.Post(request);
            var authResponse = response as AuthenticateResponse; 
            if (authResponse != null) {
                var session = base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
                session.AppId = request.AppId;
                session.ProjectId = request.ProjectId;
                this.SaveSession(session);
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mythz. the first option seems the more simply and straight forward: my problem is that I have to support soap as well. How can I accomplish the same goal using a Soap12ServiceClient instead of JsonServiceClient?

Comment: @CristianoDegiorgis Unfortunately the SOAP Service Clients doesn't enable access to the  HTTP Headers, so you're likely limited to the Custom `Meta` property added in [v4.0.35 on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet. Also have you seen [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) feature? It should negate a lot of the advantages for using SOAP.

Comment: It doesn't look like RequestFilter contains QueryString collection anymore.